# Android HTTP error (unknownhostexception) in a POST request

Tags: android, drupal, http-post

I am developing a app that makes a connection to my Drupal website.
The following the code I am attempting to use:

```
public class SignIn extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String postURL = "http://test2.icerge.com/testpoint/user";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account[name]", "Bob Kelso"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account[pass]", "awefulawefulman"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account[mail]", "bobkelso@sacredheart.org"));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                post.setEntity(ent);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                if (resEntity != null) {    
                    Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("ERROR",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But, I keep getting a `java.net.unknownhostexception`. I have INTERNET permissions set in the manifest file.

I should mention this problem is not happening on an emulator but on a real device. Why might this be malfunctioning?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when developing on Android emulators. Stop (kill) adb.exe and emulator and it usually works for me.

Comment: Yeah, happens to me as well, I have to restart the emulator every once in a while to fix this. Annoying but with the snapshots it's not so much of a pain anymore.

Comment: Hey guys,
thanks for responding but I should mention this problem is not happening on an emulator but on a real device.

Comment: I was just reading the tutorial at http://hubpages.com/hub/Tips-to-solve-the-UnknownHostException-on-Android and decided to test on an emulator. Not surpriseingly, my app didn't work just like it didn't on my real device. But, shockingly, I tried using the emulator browser to access a website to test my android.permission.INTERNET  - it didn't work.

Comment: I just found out the response data type in my code is returning an HHTP/1.1 401 error. It seems to me this might be an authrnticaion problem ?????

Answer (score 1):

401 means you need to properly authenticate: does the site use forms-based login or HTTP Basic Authentication? If it uses Basic authentication you'll need to set an appropriate *Authorization* header. See the example at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java for how to perform Basic Auth.